# Finding project that belongs to client-id

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We found a client_secrets.json in our repo and trying to find a way to see which project it belongs to. The email field is blank and the client_id is foo.apps.googleusercontent.com. Any ideas on the best way to find who it belongs to? We have hundreds of projects, so I'm hoping we can search at an organization level

Comment: I am not aware of a public API. What is the `Application Type` for this OAuth Client ID? This is the first key name in the JSON file. If the `Authorized JavaScript Origins` and `Authorized Redirect URIs` include `localhost`, the possessor of this client secret could create credentials from anywhere. Take the time to find the matching project.

Comment: Just as a kind reminder take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a Service Account it should have a filed with the `project_id` otherwise you can identify what kind of credential is this with the field `type`

On the other hand, you mentioned that the client_id is `foo.apps.googleusercontent.com` it looks like a sample key.

Like this example: [fake_client.json](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/docs-examples/blob/master/static/fake_client.json)

```
{
    "web": {
        "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "client_secret": "foo",
        "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
        "client_email": "foo@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
        "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/foo@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
        "client_id": "foo.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs"
    }
}
```